# counting upto billions for multicore processor C++ 11 or higher

Tags: c++, c++11, embedded, multicore

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
volatile int counter = 0;
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    size_t nb_iter = 1000000000;

    for( int i=0; i<nb_iter; i++){
        counter ++;
    }

    printf("counter: %ld / %ld\n", counter, nb_iter);
    return 0;
}
```

this takes about 2.19 sec to built and run the code,
how can we optimize in multicore processor?

Comment: One optimization would be to scrap the loop and just do `counter = nb_iter;`. ;)

Comment: Separate the build from the run. Since your program has just one task, it cannot be split on multiple cores.

Comment: Do you want to do something like have 8 threads, each counting a private counter up to `nb_iter/8`, and adding their counts to a shared total?  So a total of 1 billion increments happen across all cores of your CPU.  `#pragma omp parallel` can do that.  Also you can use `#pragma omp simd reduction (+:counter)` to let it vectorize, and do 4 or 8 increments per CPU instruction.  (Although it might be hard to get a compiler to optimize much without just replacing the loop with counter=nb_iter/8, if you use a non-`volatile` counter.)

Comment: Is the task to sequentially generate every value, or just to generate every value? The 1st will not benefit from multiple threads, whereas the 2nd can benefit.

Comment: Maybe have a look at parallel algos and std::reduce https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reduce

Comment: The problem here is that with `volatile` counter, you basically require each operation on that counter to be performed (its effect is a part of the observable behavior). Consequently, all those increments must be performed at runtime separately. With multiple threads, I would assume that the total runtime of these increments would be even longer, since they would additionally need to be synchronized. And, you would end up with high cache contention among cores.

Comment: Possibly related: Note that operations on a `volatile` objects are not synchronized between threads. Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/Kn499bKG6.

Comment: Remove `volatile` turn on compiler optimizations and the loop is removed (can't get more efficient than that) - live - https://godbolt.org/z/7aM1rfYe3

Answer (score 2):

> this takes about 2.19 sec to built and run the code

That's like saying "My car is slow, it does 0-100km/h in 5 days and 15 seconds" where 5 days is the time it took for the factory to build the car. Build time and execution time are two completely unrelated things not in the slightest related to each other.

> how can we optimize

The only purpose `volatile` fills in this code is to *prevent* optimization from happening. Likely because someone wanted the loop to get executed and *not* get optimized away. If you remove `volatile` the the loop will gets optimized out and everyone will be happy.

> optimize in multicore processor

You can't do that in a sensible way, since the nature of `counter++` is that it adds based on the previous value. To split the work over a number of worker threads, they should ideally be able to operate without knowing a thing about each other's results.

Sure you can create x number of threads doing dummy counting, each thread having its own counter. But I don't see the purpose with that - it's not necessarily creating any performance benefits, since you have to take the thread creation overhead in account.

It's important to understand that threads aren't some magic performance boost in every situation. You could consider creating the threads manually and benchmark from there, with or without taking thread creation overhead in account. When you have tried that and understand it, only then consider playing with things like OpenMP.